# VB code error 'runtime error 1004 in vb "method cells of object" global_failed' .

Tags: excel, vba

I got this error

`runtime error 1004 in VB "method cells of object global_failed"`

These are my codes:

```
Set oXL = EDOffice1.GetApplication()

Dim oWB As Excel.Workbook

Set oWB = EDOffice1.ActiveDocument()

Dim oSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Dim oRng As Excel.Range

Dim SUM As Long

Set oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet


Range("F1").Formula = "=SUM(" & Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(25, 2)).Address(False, False) & ")"
```

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (UNTESTED)

Change the line `Range("F1").Formula = "=SUM(" & Range(Cells(2, 2), Cells(25, 2)).Address(False, False) & ")"` to

```
With oSheet 
    .Range("F1").Formula = "=SUM(" & _
                           .Range(.Cells(2, 2), .Cells(25, 2)).Address(False, False) & _
                           ")"
End With
```

Comment: ahahah, it works perfect. Hope this is a permanent fix. The first time i tried it it works but failed after repeated running.

Comment: Change this line `Set oWB = EDOffice1.ActiveDocument()` to `Set oWB = EDOffice1.ActiveWorkbook()` if it allows you and try it?

Comment: Also use proper error handling to check if `oWB` and `oSheet` are valid objects after you set them.

Comment: No, it does not. It comes with the error "object does not support this property or method"

Comment: fine so far. Really appreciate your concern and help.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you are not inside a `sheet` code to call `Cells` without referencing the sheet.

Try to identify the sheet you want to do that and use:

```
Sheet.Range("F1").Formula = "=SUM(" & Sheet.Range(Sheet.Cells(2, 2), Sheet.Cells(25, 2)).Address(False, False) & ")"
```